# SQL Server - Dynamic SQL Stored Procedure to convert/cast columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql, sqldatatypes

Good morning,

I have been tasked with creating a stored procedure that will do the following:

1. Select Source table name,  Target table column names,  Target table Column data types and DataQualitycheckFlag from a mapping table that we have in place that specifies this information.
2. Use this information to then check each source table column that is appropriately flagged to be checked one by one to see if the data can be converted/cast to the target column data types successfully, depending on the data type .
3. If data within the source column cannot be converted, then record this problematic value within another data quality table within another database. This is so we can report back data quality issues.
4. We will then have a separate process to import the rows that could be converted to the correct data type into the target table.

I am still relatively new to SQL, however my initial thoughts were to somehow use dynamic SQL within a stored procedure to accomplish this.

Any push in the right direction would be much appreciated, preferably with an example.

Thanks.

Comment: I'd recommend you start with it and come back with a specific problem, if one arises (or more than one problem but on different questions), but show some effort. The question like it stands seems too broad.

Comment: What is your question here exactly? You're listed out your requirements, which is fine, however, you haven't really asked a question; just stated you want a push in the right direction. We don't have any sample data, or expected results to work with here, so that doesn't give us much to visualise the problem. Have you tried anything so far? (SO isn't a free coding website). Have a look at the [Asking](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking]) page on how to ask a specific question.

Answer (score 0):

You can come up with a mapping table for conversion between datatypes as specified in the [CAST and CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#implicit-conversions).

This mapping table should be used to find out, whether implicit conversion is possible or not for a column and accordingly, report has to be generated.